# Remove project info from panic messages

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, panic

How can I hide project info (like source code paths) from panic messages occurred while running a release build?

Assume following code as a Minima Reproducible Example

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello!");
    let v = vec![0];
    println!("{:?}", v[1]); // panic - index out of bounds
}
```

`> cargo build --release`
`> target/release/hello-rust`
Getting:

```
Hello!
thread 'main' panicked at 'index out of bounds: the len is 1 but the index is 1', src/main.rs:5:22
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Revealing "src/main.rs:5:22" is very unwanted. I would prefer not to reveal even that the executable build with Rust.
I would like just to exit the process with "1" error code on every `panic` situation, like index out of bounds or `.unwrap()` on error.

Tried:

```
[profile.release]
panic = "abort"
```

Didn't help.
Tried to look in [Profile Settings](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html), didn't find something useful.

Comment: Seems, this could be a good solution https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.set_hook.html

Comment: If you merely change the panic hook at runtime, the executable will still contain all the information.

Comment: @mcarton Good point. Is there a way to remove also from the executable?

Comment: strip all debug symbol I guess

Comment: You want `strip`. The rustc option got recently [stabilized](https://github.com/tmandry/rust/blob/0e13d0c20e8f64605c13c7ed6a086789e4de25cd/RELEASES.md#compiler), but using it from cargo still requires nightly(?). You can also just invoke the `strip` command on the executable from your shell. But I doubt you'll hide that the executable was made with rust.

Comment: Stripping hides most things, but one only needs to run `strings theexecutable` to realize it was written in Rust. I don't think it will possible to completely hide this, no matter what. If someone really wants to know, they will.

Comment: @ShimonS: Out of curiosity, why would you want this?

Comment: @Caesar Regarding to original question (about console messages) I suppose it's obvious. Regarding the question in comments (about the executable) - just wondering.

Comment: This is such a valid question and it's amazing how nobody cares about this. Have you ever found any solution to this?